# React Native, GraphQL, Apollo - how to create batch insert mutation

Tags: react-native, graphql, aws-appsync, appsync-apollo-client

I need to create a batch insert mutation call in react native Here is my code. will you please solve my problem. I don't know where I have done a mistake. while onHandleSubmit data is not inserting in the table.

On submitting only am passing the array of object to the batch mutation call function.

```
 onHandleSubmit = () => {
      const TestResponse = [
{
        id:1,
        userId:123,
        testId:4321,
        itemId:43545,
        attempt:true,

},
{
        id:2,
        userId:123,
        testId:4321,
        itemId:43546,
        attempt:false,

}
];
      const { ResponseStudentTestTrack = [] } = this.props;
        ResponseStudentTestTrack(TestResponse);
  }
```

Appsync Shema:

```
type StudentTestTrack {
    id: ID!
    userId: ID!
    testId: ID!
    itemId: ID!
    attempt: String!
}

type StudentTestTrackConnection {
    items: [StudentTestTrack]
    nextToken: String
}

input CreateStudentTestTrackInput {
    id: ID!
    userId: ID!
    testId: ID!
    itemId: ID!
    attempt: String!
}

type Mutation { 
batchcreateStudentTestTrack(studentTest: [CreateStudentTestTrackInput]!): [StudentTestTrack]
}
```

Apollo call:

```
 graphql(CreateStudentTestTrack, {
    props: props => ({
      ResponseStudentTestTrack: TestResponse => props.mutate({
        variables: TestResponse,
        optimisticResponse: {
          __typename: 'Mutation',
          batchcreateStudentTestTrack: { ...TestResponse, __typename: 'CoursePatternStatus' },
        },
      }),
    }),
  }),
```

mutation :

```
export const CreateStudentTestTrack = gql`
mutation batchcreateStudentTestTrack{
  batchcreateStudentTestTrack(
    studentTest:[TestResponse]
  ) {
    id,
    userId,
    testId,
    itemId,
    attempt,
  }
}`;
```

Comment: What is the type of your `ResponseStudentTestTrack` which is coming from props?

Comment: it's an array of an object like below                                                                               const TestResponse = [
{
        id:1,
        userId:123,
        testId:4321,
        itemId:43545,
        attempt:true,

},
{
        id:2,
        userId:123,
        testId:4321,
        itemId:43546,
        attempt:false,

}

Comment: I dont understand then. How are you calling it like: `ResponseStudentTestTrack(TestResponse);` If its an array you need to use `concat`

Comment: yes we can able call  ResponseStudentTestTrack through props.only concat values is passing via ResponseStudentTestTrack(TestResponse).

Comment: Just i want know how to pass array of object value in this mutation call other than its working fine for me.                                                                        export const CreateStudentTestTrack = gql`
mutation batchcreateStudentTestTrack{
  batchcreateStudentTestTrack(
    studentTest:[TestResponse]
  ) {
    id,
    userId,
    testId,
    itemId,
    attempt,
  }
}`;

Comment: Its throwing this warning while calling mutation F:\GIT\Raus\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:80 Missing field id in {
  "0": {
    "id": "670ee940-e676-11e8-887a-adaf1bf2b8bc",
    "userId": 92217,
    "testId": 1232

Comment: So there is something in your Schema which is required, and you're not passing it to the mutation I think

Comment: all the missing fields are available in my mutation call. I think did mistake in batch creation mutation i don't how to pass array values in the batch mutation that's my issue.

Comment: I assume there's an APPSync API behind this schema. What the API is returning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to something wrong with client side mutation. Try this.

```
export const CreateStudentTestTrack = gql`
mutation abc ( // could be anyname
  $studentTest: [CreateStudentTestTrackInput] // Type of input mentioned in graphql definition
) {
  batchcreateStudentTestTrack(studentTest: $studentTest) {
    id,
    userId,
    testId,
    itemId,
    attempt,
  }
}`;
```

Also try removing optimistic response inside your graphql parameter if don't need to update ui cache and if your mutation call is just for insert. Also I have updated the mutate object based on my solutions. Please look into it too.

```
graphql(CreateStudentTestTrack, {
    props: props => ({
      ResponseStudentTestTrack: TestResponse => props.mutate({
        variables: {
          studentTest: TestResponse
        },
      }),
    }),
  }),
```

Also check you destructuring code.

```
const { ResponseStudentTestTrack } = this.props; // don't set default value as array for a function prop.
```

Try this code and you face issues comment below.